# Vue 2 - Duplicate Vue.js Instances

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have created a Vue.js library and included it in a Nuxt.js project. The problem is that I'm seeing duplicate Vue.js instances being created from both the Nuxt instance and the library, whereas the library should use the Vue instance from Nuxt.js:

[image: Screenshot]

You can see it's being printed twice from two different instances.

**How can I make sure that only one instance is used?** This is causing all sorts of issues.

Things I have already done:

- The webpack configuration of the library has `'vue'` as an external dependency. (How is it possible that even though it is marked as external in the library the library still dynamically imports it?)
- `'vue'` is a `peerDependency` in the `package.json` file of the library.

Additional information:

- The library is included in the Nuxt project using `npm link`
- This eventually causes errors of the sort of `$attrs is readonly.` errors and such.
- This only happens in development, production builds seem to be working fine. No errors.
- The first instance is from `webpack:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e` (Nuxt.js presumably)
- The second instance is from `webpack-internal:///../minerva/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js` (the library)

The library exports this component and has this webpack configuration:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Renderer from '../Renderer';
import {default as Attributes} from '../attributes/main';

const renderer = new Renderer();

renderer.registerAttributeType(Attributes.Bold);
renderer.registerAttributeType(Attributes.Color);

export default Vue.extend(
    {
        name: 'RenderPlane',
        props: {
            parsed: {
                type: Array,
                required: true
            }
        },

        render: function (createElement) {
            return createElement(renderer.render(this.parsed), null);
        }
    });
```

```js
const path = require('path')
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')

module.exports = () => {
  return {
    mode: 'development',
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'source'),
    entry: {
      main: './main.ts',
      compiler: './renderer/main.ts',
      formatter: './formatter/main.ts',
      highlighter: './highlighter/main.ts',
      parser: './parser/main.ts'
    },

    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
      clean: true,
      library: {
        type: 'umd',
        name: 'Minerva'
      }
    },

    target: 'web',
    devtool: 'source-map',

    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          use: 'ts-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
          test: /\.pegjs$/,
          use: 'pegjs-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.vue$/,
          loader: 'vue-loader'
        }
      ],
    },

    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.pegjs', '.vue', '.ts', '.js'],
      symlinks: false
    },

    externals: {
      vue: {
        commonjs: 'vue',
        commonjs2: 'vue',
        amd: 'vue',
        root: 'Vue'
      }
    },

    plugins: [
      new VueLoaderPlugin()
    ],
  }
}
```

It is imported and used in the Nuxt project like so:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

import {Parser, RenderPlane} from '@pilend-personal-stack/minerva';

const parser = new Parser();

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'editor',

  components: {
    RenderPlane
  },

  data() {
    return {
      source: '',
      parsed: []
    };
  },

  watch: {
    source: function (val) {
      try {
        this.parsed = parser.process(val);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error updating data: ' + err);
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    printParsed() {
      try {
        return JSON.stringify(this.parsed, null, 2);
      } catch (err) {
        return err.message;
      }
    }
  }

})
```

If you can help me out with this you have my eternal gratitude.

Comment: Could you please use a `Plugin` for importing your library and see if the problem remains?

Comment: @ImanShafiei I have used a Plugin and passed the Vue instance down to all components from the library. Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: I posted an answer, If you find it helpful, please consider accepting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, You should use a `Plugin` for importing your library.

For example, I have a file named my-custom-plugin.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueQuillEditor from 'vue-quill-editor'

Vue.use(VueQuillEditor)
```

And in the `nuxt.config.js`

```
plugins: [
    {
        src: '~plugins/nuxt-quill-plugin',
        ssr: false
    }
],
```

It should solve your problem.

Comment: This solved my multiple messages issue for both `element-tiptap` & `vue-cron-editor-buefy`. Seems it could be those packages including Vue in their dependencies and not peerDependencies, and the way they are importing Vue, causing multiple bundled Vue?